# Why does LoadLibrary succeed or fail depending on the current directory?

Tags: delphi, firefox, delphi-xe2, loadlibrary

I'm having issues with LoadLibrary, something that never occurred to me before, this is the first time i see this, i'm trying to load a module "nss3.dll" inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\" with LoadLibrary, in order to import some functions from it, but it fails with 0 return value, i tried hard-coding a .dll from system32 folder and it worked fine, any ideas what's happening ?

Edit: I forgot to mention, a way to overcome this issue is to call SetCurrentDirectory and THEN import the module without specifying the path to the .dll, but that's not the case, i want to find out why it's happening to me.

Edit: Here's some snippet (this works):

```
var
  NSSModule: HModule;
begin
  SetCurrentDir('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox');
  NSSModule := LoadLibrary('nss3.dll');
```

This, does not works, no idea why...:

```
var
  NSSModule: HModule;
begin
  NSSModule := LoadLibrary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\nss3.dll');
```

Comment: We can't debug code you don't show us. If you want help figuring out why your code isn't working, **post your code**. Until then, you can read the documentation at MSDN for [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the part about how it locates the libraries.

Comment: Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit? You cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process (or vice versa)...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz GetLastError returns 126 (Module not found), the funny part is the .dll is THERE.

Comment: @jlahd my application is 32bit running on a 64bit Windows, the .dll is 32bit i think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dll you are loading is trying to statically load another dll in the same folder (mozglue.dll). That's why when you set the working directory it works. When you don't, since firefox's path is not in the system path, the api cannot find the dll. You can find specifics about dll search [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The explanation for this is that the DLL itself links to other DLLs that live in the same directory. You cannot load the DLL without also loading these other dependencies. And it is the loader's attempt to load the dependencies that is failing.

The expected host for this DLL is Firefox, which is also found in that same directory. When Firefox loads the DLL, the dependencies are resolved successfuilly because the DLL search path searches the directory containing the executable. But when your program attempts to load the module, the dependent modules cannot be found because the your executable is in a different directory.

The error code that you report is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. This refers to one of the dependencies rather than the module you loaded. In fact that is common with loader errors. You may encounter hard to believe error codes but usually the explanation is that they refer to a error resolving a dependent module.

Modifying the working directory is not the solution. That does resolve your problem but you should not rely on the working directory for dependency resolution. The system provided mechanisms to influence DLL search are `SetDllDirectory` or `AddDllDirectory`. For instance:

```
SetDllDirectory('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox');
NSSModule := LoadLibrary('nss3.dll');
SetDllDirectory(nil);
```

The MSDN topic [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) is required reading here.

Comment: I did something different, I called LoadLibrary on mozglue.dll before loading nss3.dll, works too.

Comment: That's pretty brittle too. I don't know why you don't do it the standard way.